# Ionic Creator + Cordova Barcode Scanner write : false

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, barcode-scanner

I have written a VERY simple Ionic package (as part of a test) to fire up the barcode scanner

I have installed cordova-plugin-barcodescanner and am using the following

```
$scope.scanBarcode = function() {

    $cordovaBarcodeScanner
      .scan()
      .then(function(barcodeData) {
        alert(barcodeData);
      }, function(error) {
        alert(error);
      });
}
```

I then have a very simple

```
<button ng-click="scanBarcode()">Scan</button>
```

I have compiled the app, generated my apk, installed on a device, confirmed that the application has permissions enabled for camera (and storage).

When I click the scan button, an error is firing which is

**write settings: false**

I am at a loss where to start as there is no specific error docs for barcodescanner.

Just to advise I have been able to use the cordova-plugin-camera ok with ionic creator after compiling the app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually I also encountered this issue, it will probably happen for Android 6.0 and above.

Inside the plugin, these following codes are the one triggering it.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP + 1) {
      Class systemClass = Settings.System.class;
      try {
          Method canWriteMethod = systemClass.getDeclaredMethod("canWrite", Context.class);
          boolean retVal = (Boolean) canWriteMethod.invoke(null, this.cordova.getActivity());
          Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Can Write Settings: " + retVal);
          if (!retVal && !action.equals("requestWriteSettings") && !action.equals("getWriteSettings")) {
              //can't write Settings
              this.callbackContext.error("write settings: false");
              return false;
          }
          this.writeSettings = retVal;
      } catch (Exception ignored) {
          Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Could not perform permission check");
          this.callbackContext.sendPluginResult(new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.ILLEGAL_ACCESS_EXCEPTION));
      }
  }
```

So I think we need to inform the plugin creators or submit a fix for this one.

**Temporarily what you can do is either you by pass it, by commenting the whole block I shared.** Seems like it's working from my side, haven't checked if this is actually used somewhere in the codes. Why it must be called.

**Another proper way, which is to enhance the code by implementing the following:**

A. Include in the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
```

B. The allow or ask the user to allow the write settings, by calling the intent needed:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + this.cordova.getActivity().getPackageName()));
this.cordova.getActivity().startActivity(intent);
```

**UPDATE**

C. This is suggested by MoleDesign, as mentioned in one of the answer below. Another solution which is a workaround is to lower the sdk version, in the project.properties change it it to:

```
target=android-23
```

Comment: I did most of these with no success, however I have fixed the issue, which I will document below

Comment: However thanks for the details, i DIDNT alter the plugin itself, but maybe you could submit your findings to the GIT repo?

Comment: I have linked to this question on the cordova git for reference as your work seems invaluable

Comment: Acceptign this answer as mine is a workaround not a solution, you may want to include the work around in your answer just for now to make it more complete for anyone having this problem

Comment: Hi @MOLEDesign, yep that would also work but basically it would be using lower sdk.. thanks for sharing though, let me add that in the answer. Currently meaning so far you are ok with a lower version? but yep let me also submit my finding in the git repo.

Comment: WHERE IS object.properties LOCATED??

Comment: Hi @Prasobh.K, it's actually project.properties.. it's inside the platforms/android.. when you added the platform android in the project.

Answer (score 0):

It appears from SDK-25 and above some of the cordova plugins have issues. I got around my problem by changing project.properties file from

```
target=android-25
```

to

```
target=android-23
```

This may also work on 24, but I did not have that SDK installed

As soon as a built the app, the barcode reader worked fine

Answer (score 0):

I also had this error and managed to fix it by reverting `cordova-plugin-barcodescanner` from version `0.7.1` to version `0.7.0`

Hope this saves someone the hours of frustration I had trying to fix this error.